# How to generate resources files on linux using dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

On Windows we can use Resgen.exe to generate .resources files from txt files.On linux how can i achieve the same using .NET Core?

Comment: I have done similar, but within .net. What I did was to simply copy-paste the code for al.exe and resgen from mono project.

Comment: @Yahya please can you provide me the link for the code

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/resgen/monoresgen.cs

Comment: @Yahya: Thank you