# How to create resource sattelite assemblies for localization from resx and restext files in .NET Core desktop app using MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj, resx, avaloniaui

I am using a Linux development system and the Rider IDE to develop a cross-platform desktop application with AvaloniaUI. I am trying to follow the following Microsoft Documentation regarding the creation of resource-files for localization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/resources

Given the resources I want to capture and localize are all strings, I have opted to extract constant string definitions from my view models into dedicated .restext files.

Then, I updated the .csproj project file as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" InitialTargets="GenerateAsembliesFromResourceBinaries">

...


<ItemGroup>
        <StringResource Include="**/*.restext" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <Target Name="GenerateResourceBinaries">
        <!-- resgen.exe resources.fr.txt -->
        <GenerateResource Sources="@(StringResource)" OutputResources="@(StringResource->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(Filename).resources')">
            <Output TaskParameter="OutputResources" ItemName="ResourceBinary" />
        </GenerateResource>
    </Target>
    
    <Target Name="GenerateAsembliesFromResourceBinaries" DependsOnTargets="GenerateResourceBinaries">
        <!-- al /t:lib /embed:resources.fr.resources /culture:fr /out:fr\Example1.resources.dll -->
        <AL TargetType="library"
            EmbedResources="@(ResourceBinary)"
            Culture="%(ResourceBinary.Culture)"
            OutputAssembly="%(ResourceBinary.Culture)\$(TargetName).resources.dll">

            <Output TaskParameter="OutputAssembly"
                    ItemName="SatelliteAssemblies"/>
        </AL>
    </Target>
```

**For reference:**

- GenerateResource Task corresponds to ResGen.exe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/generateresource-task?view=vs-2022
- AL Task corresponds to AL.exe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/al-assembly-linker-task?view=vs-2022

However, building the project now results in the following error:

> MyApp.csproj(135, 9): ResGen.exe not supported on .NET Core MSBuild

I cannot find anything in the linked .NET resources documentation which suggests the process does not work for .NET Core, nor any alternative approach for creating resource sattelite-assemblies using .NET Core MSBuild.

What is the proper way to accomplish this without using ResGen.exe and AL.exe?

Edit: this may be a duplicate of [How to generate resources files on linux using dotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760060/how-to-generate-resources-files-on-linux-using-dotnet)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4082